# Not able to display validation message with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am having problem with AJAX on an ASP.NET MVC view page. I have a form where consist of an input field and a button to submit it and the form is making use of `Ajax.BeginForm` to render submitted data on a table dynamically. The `UpdateTargetId` aims to the `div` which wraps a partial view where this table stays on.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("InsertMissingItems", "MissingItem", new AjaxOptions { , HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "itemList" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Statu, new { id = "hdnStatu" })
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group" lang="tr">
                        @Html.Label("Miktar", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 text-left" })
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control", id = "itemQuantity" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessage("Quantity", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                            <button class="btn btn-success col-lg-4" type="submit" id="btnAdd" onclick="return Validation(@((int)Enums.MissingItem.Add))"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Ekle</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id='itemList'>
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ReturnOrder/ItemListControl.cshtml");}
        </div>
}
```

The problem is, when I want to use validation, the error message is not displayed. For example; `@Html.ValidationMessage("Quantity", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` is never being displayed even if I tried to submit the form empty. I implemented the validation attributes and messages in the model class properly and also included all of the necessary script files which is related with this operation in my view file.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you confirm that Jquery unobtrusive validation javascript is referenced on your layout or same view?

Comment: @codein, Yes, it is referenced.

Comment: Could you also confirm that the onclick handler in the submit button is functioning as expected? I could not reproduce this issue using your exact form excluding the submit event handler on submit button.
Check that you are adding Required attribute on the properties that are required on the model. also confirm again that 
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") if available on the bundles config is referenced or reference the script directly.